# A word for a list of definitions

Tags: single-word-requests

I am preparing a technical document for a new version of a web application I have created, and towards the beginning of the document I am going to list a few of the terms I will be using in the document, along with a short definition or explanation of how I am using the term.  This is just to make sure that the words are understood the way I intend.

There is a word for just such a list. I know there is.  I just can't come up with it.  Aarrgghh!

Comment: **glossary**...

Comment: @ermanen: Yes, you're right. How could I have forgotten?  So, you don't want to put this in as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[glossary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glossary)**

> a list of terms in a special subject, field, or area of usage, with accompanying definitions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on what you think sounds better in your particular case, but ***glossary*** and ***list of terminology*** are best, and ***dictionary*** might also do...

I've also seen plain old ***definitions*** used, particularly when the author explains how to understand common terms in a given context (eg. the documentation for a flight search engine might define how they understand "flight", "route", etc.)